# UVM error when using multiple sequencers using for loop construct

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a sort of following code in the body of my UVM virtual seq:

```
begin:
  for(int x=0; x<8; x++) begin
    
    fork begin
      automatic int x_idx = x;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) begin
          if(!my_sequence[x_idx].randomize() with {...}
          my_sequence[x_idx].start(p_sequencer.my_sequencer[x_idx];
        end
    end join_none
  end
end
```

Code information:

1. I have 8 sequencers each receiving its own sequence. Hence the first "for loop" with 8 iterations.
2. After going through some tutorials I understood that using fork-join I can run the 8 sequences to the 8 sequencers in parallel.

But when I run the code I get error on the "if(!my_sequence..." line of code. Error being:

```
The object is being used before it was constructed/allocated.
```

I also tested the code by getting rid of the outer for loop and instead using index numbers as follows:

```
    fork begin
      automatic int x_idx = x;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) begin
          if(!my_sequence[0].randomize() with {...}
          my_sequence[0].start(p_sequencer.my_sequencer[0];
        end
    end join_none

    fork begin
      automatic int x_idx = x;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) begin
          if(!my_sequence[0].randomize() with {...}
          my_sequence[1].start(p_sequencer.my_sequencer[1];
        end
    end join_none
    ...
```

This seems to work. But I want to write better code with for loop.

Another info: While debugging using DVE I saw the x_idx value to be 8. Not sure why it is showing as 8 and also not sure if that's the reason for the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you placed the `x_idx` declaration inside the `begin/end` block that is inside the `fork/join_none`. You don't want the initialization to happen when the parallel threads start executing; you want it to happen as each iteration of the for loop executes. You should write it as

```
begin
  for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
    fork
      int x_idx = x;
      for(int i=0; i<100; i++) begin
         if(!my_sequence[x_idx].randomize() with {...}
         my_sequence[x_idx].start(p_sequencer.my_sequencer[x_idx];
      end
   join_none
end
```

Also, there's no need to use the `automatic` keyword inside a class—all variables declared inside a class method have an implicit automatic lifetime.

Note that declarations inside fork/join's initialize upon hitting the fork block, not when the statements inside the fork begin their threads. The declarations are not separate threads. You could also write as:

```
begin
  for(int x=0; x<8; x++) begin
    int x_idx = x;
    fork
      for(int i=0; i<100; i++) begin
         if(!my_sequence[x_idx].randomize() with {...}
         my_sequence[x_idx].start(p_sequencer.my_sequencer[x_idx];
      end
   join_none
  end
end
```

In both cases, there is a new instance of `x_idx` for every loop iteration, but the statements inside the `fork/join_none` don't begin executing until *after* all iterations complete.

Comment: But the statement "int x_idx=x" is still inside the fork/join_none block. Isn't that what we want to avoid?

Comment: See added note.